# Why is my Posgres connection shutting down on Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, flask

I'm working with a Python/Flask web app deployed to Heroku. The site currently works fine locally, both with the Flask and the Heroku local web servers. When I attempt to load the site, however, I get the following error:

```
2019-05-26T00:48:39.457829+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-05-26 00:48:39,451] ERROR in app: Exception on /survey/rwubxbi8 [GET]
2019-05-26T00:48:39.457845+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-05-26T00:48:39.457847+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
2019-05-26T00:48:39.457848+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor, statement, parameters, context
2019-05-26T00:48:39.457850+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 552, in do_execute
2019-05-26T00:48:39.457851+00:00 app[web.1]: cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2019-05-26T00:48:39.457853+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.AdminShutdown: terminating connection due to administrator command
2019-05-26T00:48:39.457854+00:00 app[web.1]: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

If I then log in to a bash shell with `heroku run bash`, and enter the Flask shell, I'm able to perform the same query without trouble.

```
$ heroku run bash --remote staging
Running bash on ⬢ ****-survey-staging... up, run.9548 (Hobby)
~ $ flask shell
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 21:35:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
App: app.create_app [production]
Instance: /app/instance
>>> Survey
<class 'app.models.Survey'>
>>> survey = Survey.select_by_user_slug('rwubxbi8')
>>> survey
<Survey: "vk6cwyjb">
>>>
```

According to the Heroku logs, this is the query where the problem happens.

Here's the complete Heroku log:

https://pastebin.com/m1GQgEeX

**Edit**:

As requested, here's the code where the error is occurring:

```python
    @classmethod
    def select_by_user_slug(cls, slug):
        """Return the survey that contains the given user slug.

        :param slug: The user slug stored within a survey.
        :return: The survey containing the user slug."""
        return cls.query.filter(cls._user_slugs.contains(slug)).first_or_404()
```

Again, the code works fine locally and executing the exact same method within a Flask shell also works.

**Edit 2**:

OK, just tried it again, exact same URL, and it worked. Tried with a different URL that would return the same survey, that also worked.

But I'd like to prevent this happening again. This happened on two stages of the app. When it happened on one, I tried on a test stage and a production stage and it happened on both.

If anyone has an idea why this happened, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: can you post your code where this process is being executed?